# Why are there such large disparities about the efficacy of a covid-19 vaccine agaisnt the same variants?

Tags: covid-19, research

I've seen this before with other vaccines (such as Sputnik V and Astrazeneca) but this time since there is no apparent way to justify it, it caught my attention . The efficacy of the Pfizer vaccine against the delta variant has many different figures according to different studies,

[Pfizer Biontech vaccine 70% effective against delta variant](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/health/pfizer-biontech-vaccine-70-effective-against-delta-variant-study/2294355)

[Pfizer vaccine had an efficacy of 88% after both doses.](https://scroll.in/article/999282/explained-whats-the-delta-plus-variant-and-will-covid-19-vaccines-work-against-it)

[Pfizer vaccine efficacy only at 64%](https://time.news/delta-variant-pfizer-vaccine-efficacy-only-at-64/)

[Vaccine effectiveness against hospital admission with the Delta variant 96%](https://www.fiercepharma.com/pharma/two-shots-pfizer-astrazeneca-vaccine-effective-against-delta-variant-says-u-k-real-world)

Assuming (4) and (1) - (3) are talking about efficacy for different situations with no clarification (hospitalizations and deaths vs getting infected), there are still no way to make coherence of all the different figures. What does this have to do with? Standards for the studies? Population having different levels of immunity due to genetics,  reinfection? Same variants of concern having mutations? any known reason?

Why are there such large disparities about the efficacy of a covid-19 vaccine agaisnt the same variants?

Comment: At a minimum you should consider whether the confidence intervals around these estimates suggest they are actually different numbers at all.

Comment: Your links are all to news stories, not to scientific studies.  Reading the actual studies or scientific information should answer your question.